# How can I trace the issue why .ipa is not showing into TestFlight?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode9.2

I'm uploading .ipa file during every release and successfully did that many times but suddenly from the morning, It's not showing into TestFlight. I'm doing the same process as I did previous builds.It shows me successfully uploaded like previous and even showing processing in *activity* tab view *(like: below image)* into **iTunes connect** after that it's not coming into **TestFlight**. 
What's the reason for that? how can I trace the issue?

**Xcode Version:** Version 9.2

**My Steps:** Product > Archive > Export > Uploading via Application Loader.

[image]

Comment: This is more likely to be an issue with iTunes Connect rather than anything you are doing. I don't think there is anything we can help with here

Comment: So sad! then How can I reach them/ their support?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/

Comment: thanks then I'm trying to reach them.

Comment: Apple will send the mail regarding the problem. Check that for help.

Comment: Did you get an email that the build is ready? Do you see the build in activity tab after processing is done?

Comment: Yes I got it after 3 days of submission